# EmguCV EigenFace recognizer VB.net IImage

Tags: vb.net, opencv, emgucv, computer-vision

I have a question, I am using EmguCV for a school project to detect faces. It works.
But when I try to implement the EigenFace alogrithm, I find some thing that I don't understand. (I seached for it on the internet but it is only C# what I find).

My problem:

```
Dim recognizer As New EigenFaceRecognizer(80, Double.PositiveInfinity)
recoginzer.train(..., ...)
```

The problem is that I don't know what I have to fill in at the ...
It says: images() as Emgu.CV.IImage
And: labels() as integer

So does anyone know what to fill in here?

Thanks in advance,
Lars Jansen
The Netherlands

Comment: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/2c4e34d5-0dab-a959-e0e6-aa86065c2031.htm

Comment: I already read that but wat is a IImage andere how do I make an array of them. Andere wat about the label array as integer?

Comment: I can't see an inheritance list, so I believe you'll need to create a class implementing the `IImage` interface. By looking at the [members](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/3e08f9ed-e851-1a37-89c4-80369f5bf988.htm) it seems doable.

Comment: About the labels I think it's either an array of numeric labels, or an array of pointers to strings (IntPtr).

Comment: I seriously have no idea on how to do that...

Comment: I can post an example. Not all methods/properties implemented, but as a starting point.